# how to use network printer for print blade using laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-8

i have a bill blade in laravel. i need to print that bill in a particular network printer.Now i use dompdf for stream() but doesnot print . and i have no idea for connecting a printer in the section

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#Kitchen" ).click(function(e) {
            var orderid = $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-id');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:"{{url('Send-Order-to-Kitchen')}}/"+orderid,
                data:{
                    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    // console.log(data);
                    toastr.options = {
                        "closeButton": true,
                        "newestOnTop": true,
                        "positionClass": "toast-top-right"
                    };
                    toastr.success(data.msg);
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    if (xhr.status == 401) {
                        window.location.href = "{{url('staff/login')}}";
                    }else if(xhr.status == 200){
                        window.location.href = "{{url('staff/login')}}";
                    }
                }
            
            });
        });
     });
    </script>
```

```
public function Sendordertokitchen($id){
        set_time_limit(180);
        Order::where('id',$id)->update(['status' => 1]);
        $order = Order::find(22);
        // return view('manager/kitchen_receipt',compact('order'));
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('manager/kitchen_receipt', compact('order'));
        $file = 'Kitchen_Print_'.$order->token_id.'.pdf';
        return $pdf->download($file);    
        // return response()->json(['msg' => 'Order menus send to the kitchen successfully']);
    }
```

Comment: I've removed the [tag:html] and [tag:css] tags, since the question has nothing to do with those aspects of web-design.

Comment: hai everyone,is there any  ideas for the solution?